# Laravel not picking up Mocked class

Tags: laravel, phpunit

In my controller I am using a class like so:

```
public function book($id, CalRequest $request)
{
    $event = $this->repo->find($id);

    (new CalAuthorisation())
        ->setEvent($event)
        ->canBook();

    $this->booking->book($event, $request);
}
```

I'm mocking a class like below:

```
$auth = \Mockery::mock(CalAuthorisation::class)->makePartial();
$this->app->bind(CalAuthorisation::class, function() use ($auth) {
    return $auth;
});

$auth->shouldReceive('canBook')->once()->andReturn(true);
```

However, if I `dd` within the `canBook()` function I still get into there. I have a similar mock in place for the `CalRequest` class which works fine. Any suggestions as to why this isn't working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency injection is about injecting different implementation into your logic. When using new keyword, `PHP` will fetch a certain class and only that class. `Laravel` solves dependency injection through the container, so you have to use the container for it to work.

There is two ways, either use `app()` or `resolve()`. Secondly you can inject your classes into methods that are on `Laravel` classes like jobs, commands, controllers etc. and this will be resolved through the container.

Using `resolve()`.

```
resolve(new CalAuthorisation())
    ->setEvent($event)
    ->canBook();
```

Injecting it, through the controller method.

```
public function book($id, CalRequest $request, CalAuthorisation $calAuth)
{
    $event = $this->repo->find($id);

    $calAuth->setEvent($event)
        ->canBook();
```